# How to have more than one element change behaviour when an element is clicked

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails project where I want the content below the header to hide when the menu toggler is clicked, for devices with a width less than 1024px. This is what I have in my application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>  
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

My header is structured like this:

```
<header>
  <%= image_tag('logo.png', alt: 'logo', class: 'small_device_image') %>
  <nav class="site-nav">
    <ul class="menu">
      <%= image_tag('logo.png', alt: 'logo', class: 'style_image') %>
      <li>
        <%= link_to root_path do %>
          <h6>Home</h6>
        <% end %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to "pages/our-programmes" do %>
          <h6>Our Programmes</h6>
        <% end %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to "pages/about-us" do %>
          <h6>About Us</h6>
        <% end %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to new_contact_path do %>
          <h6>Contact Us</h6>
        <% end %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="menu-toggle">
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Below, is the accompanying scss:

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: $blue;
  color: $white;
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: relative;
}

header::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.small_device_image {
  background-color: $white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em;
  left: 2em;
}

.site-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: $white;
  clip-path: circle(0% at top);
  transition: clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;
  .menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
}

.style_image {
  background-color: $white;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.site-nav-open {
  clip-path: circle(150% at top);
}

.site-nav .menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid $dark-blue;
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: $yellow;
    color: $blue;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: $primary-font;
    padding: 2em 4em;
    &:hover {
      background-color: indianred;
      color: gold;
    }
  }
}

.site-nav .menu li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.menu-toggle {
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.2em;
  right: .75em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: $bright-white;
  height: 3px;
  width: 1.75em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

.hamburger::before {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.open .hamburger{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.open .hamburger::before {
  opacity: 0;
} 

.open .hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  header {
    height: 75px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .style_image {
    display: none;
  }
  .site-nav .menu {
    height: calc(100vh - 155px);
    li {
      position: relative;
      height: 25%;
      a {
      height: calc(((100vh - 155px) / 4) - 1px);
      padding: 0;
      }
      h6 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
    }
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .small_device_image {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .photo {
    display: none;
  }
  .site-nav {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: right;
    clip-path: initial;
    .menu li {
      display: inline-block;
      border: none;
      a {
        color: $white;
        background: transparent;
        padding: 0;
        margin-left: 2em;
        &:hover {
          background-color: transparent;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have added some jQuery in my application.js file. However, it doesn't hide what is in the div with the class, "container-fluid". What I want is for the content in the container-fluid class to disappear when the menu toggler is clicked and to appear when it is toggled off (I hope this makes sense :) ):

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
        $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav-open');
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.container.fluid').hide();
  })
});
```

I understand that I have put in a lot of code and it may not make sense. If anyone can be of any assistance, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors when you run this?

Comment: Nope, no console errors.

Comment: Can you please specify what you're seeing or not seeing when you run this? The jquery code works fine, so is it the styling that's not working or is nothing happening at all when clicking the hamburger icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not running rails, so it's slightly difficult to pinpoint your exact issue.

The `jQuery` code you've written works, however, there is a typo in your code: try replacing ".container.fluid" with "container-fluid" in your `jQuery` and see if that resolves the issue.

**Edit:**

To toggle visibility of the .container-fluid element, this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav-open');
        $('.container-fluid').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

With the additional css:

```
.active {
  display: none;
}
```

Hope this helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav-open');
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.container-fluid').hide();
  })
});
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: $blue;
  color: $white;
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: relative;
}

header::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.small_device_image {
  background-color: $white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em;
  left: 2em;
}

 ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: max-content;
  }

.site-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: $white;
  clip-path: circle(0% at top);
  transition: clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;
}

.style_image {
  background-color: $white;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.site-nav-open {
  clip-path: circle(150% at top);
}

.site-nav .menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid $dark-blue;
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: $yellow;
    color: $blue;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: $primary-font;
    padding: 2em 4em;
    &:hover {
      background-color: indianred;
      color: gold;
    }
  }
}

.site-nav .menu li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.menu-toggle {
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.2em;
  right: .75em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: $bright-white;
  height: 3px;
  width: 1.75em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

.hamburger::before {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.open .hamburger {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.open .hamburger::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  header {
    height: 75px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .style_image {
    display: none;
  }
  .site-nav .menu {
    height: calc(100vh - 155px);
    li {
      position: relative;
      height: 25%;
      a {
        height: calc(((100vh - 155px) / 4) - 1px);
        padding: 0;
      }
      h6 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
    }
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .small_device_image {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .photo {
    display: none;
  }
  .site-nav {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: right;
    clip-path: initial;
    .menu li {
      display: inline-block;
      border: none;
      a {
        color: $white;
        background: transparent;
        padding: 0;
        margin-left: 2em;
        &:hover {
          background-color: transparent;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<header>
    <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul class="menu">
        <%= image_tag('logo.png', alt: 'logo', class: 'style_image') %>
          <li>
            <%= link_to root_path do %>
              <h6>Home</h6>
              <% end %>
          </li>
          <li>
            <%= link_to "pages/our-programmes" do %>
              <h6>Our Programmes</h6>
              <% end %>
          </li>
          <li>
            <%= link_to "pages/about-us" do %>
              <h6>About Us</h6>
              <% end %>
          </li>
          <li>
            <%= link_to new_contact_path do %>
              <h6>Contact Us</h6>
              <% end %>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <div class="hamburger">V</div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you @Mark! It's amazing what a second pair of eyes can do.

If I wanted the container-fluid to reappear when I close the menu toggler, how could I amend my jQuery code?

Comment: I've edited my answer with jquery which will fix that as well. Please be sure to mark as answered if this helps!